# Why when I upload some images, and the result is only one image uploaded

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Here I use 'Codeigniter', In my method....
To upload an image, I use an Ajax call, and my ajax data is taken from the value .attr ('src') from tag 'img',
Value of the data is base64 code.

page_ajax_call.php

```
if ( isset($_POST['data_image_post']) ) {
   $to_upload   = 'users/VegetaSSJ/images/user_pp.png';
   $to_convert  = 'users/VegetaSSJ/images/'.time().'.jpg';
   $img_base64  = $this->input->post('data_image_post');

    list( $type, $data ) = explode(';', $img_base64);
    list( , $data )          = explode(',', $img_base64);
    $decode      = base64_decode($data);

    file_put_contents($to_upload, $decode);
    $ori_img_base64 = imagecreatefrompng($to_upload);
    imagejpeg($ori_img_base64, $to_convert, 100);
    unlink($to_upload);
}
```

Ajax.js

```
$('.wrap-img-attachment img').each(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url     : "home",
      type    : "post",
      data    : {'data_image_post': $(this).attr('src')},
      success : function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  });
```

Please, correct the error on my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when single ajax call is sent to the server it save the file to 'users/VegetaSSJ/images/user_pp.png'
so the next request will override this file 
so you need to change it by adding time stamp like what you have done in the convert file path

```
  $to_upload   = 'users/VegetaSSJ/images/'.time().'user_pp.png';
```

so each request will save the image to unique file without overlapping